# How to minimize time in mySQL select query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-optimization

I have this query wherein I want to find out the sales for the current year and the sales for last year. I cannot make it into 2 separate queries since it has to be of the same item code. Meaning the item codes used in the sales for the current year must also be the item codes used for the sales last year.

The code below is working but it takes almost 8 to 9 minutes to fetch

```
select p.itemcode, 
       p.itemdescription, 
       (  select round((SUM(SA.QUANTITY*P.SellingPrice)),2) 
          from sales s 
          join product p on s.itemcode=p.itemcode 
          where YEAR(s.date) = 2013
       ),       
       (  select round((SUM(SA.QUANTITY * P.SellingPrice)),2) 
          from sales s 
          join product p on s.itemcode=p.itemcode 
          where YEAR(s.date) = 2012
       )
from product p 
join supplier s on p.suppliercode = s.suppliercode
join currency c on c.countrycode=s.countrycode
join country co on co.countrycode=c.countrycode
JOIN SALES SA ON SA.ITEMCODE=P.ITEMCODE
where c.countrycode = 'NZ'
group by p.itemcode
limit 10
```

Ideally the output should be

```
Itemcode    Itemdescription        SalesforCurrentYear    SalesforLastYear
GS771516    BUBBLE PARTY MACHINE   1035300.00             2079300.00
GSNBC-025   X'MAS HOUSE        600612.25              1397163.25
GSNBC-031   BRANDENBURGER TOR      741010.75              1572207.25
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Please show your table structures (at least the fields used) and identify your primary keys. Edit your question to show this.

Comment: Setting up proper indexes might be helpful as well.

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query can be simplified by eliminating two joins:

```
select .......
       .......
from product p 
join supplier s on p.suppliercode = s.suppliercode
JOIN SALES SA ON SA.ITEMCODE=P.ITEMCODE
where s.countrycode = 'NZ'
group by p.itemcode
limit 10
```

Afterwards, two dependent subqueries in the select clause can be reduced to one outer join:

```
select p.itemcode, 
       p.itemdescription, 
       round((SUM(  CASE WHEN YEAR(s.date) = 2013
                    THEN SA.QUANTITY*P.SellingPrice  
                    ELSE 0 END
            )),2) As Sum2013,    
       round((SUM(  CASE WHEN YEAR(s.date) = 2012
                    THEN SA.QUANTITY * P.SellingPrice
                    ELSE 0 END
            )),2) As Sum2012
from product p 
join supplier s on p.suppliercode = s.suppliercode
LEFT JOIN SALES SA ON SA.ITEMCODE=P.ITEMCODE
where s.countrycode = 'NZ'
group by p.itemcode
limit 10
```

Please try this query and let us know how it will perform.

Answer (score 0):

Follow any of these steps

1.You can parse your query.

2.Remove redundant statements.

3.Use inner join or outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You've got sales three times in the same scope.  I'd get rid of two of those, and that should help.  Also, in terms of business logic, all of these tables seem mandatory for a sale.  If that's true, you should use "inner join", for compatibility with standard SQL - even though it's the same in MySQL.